# Put spaces around all punctuation but excluding apostrophes

Tags: r, gsub, punctuation

I'm new to this, so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question... I need help with a bit of code in R...

I have a bit of code (below) which puts a space around all my punctuation in all txt files in a folder. It's lovely, but I don't want it to add space around apostrophes (') -

Can anybody help me exclude apostrophes in that bit gsub("(\.+|[[:punct:]])", " \1 " ---?
Or is that how you would do it? (with [^ ?)

I get this:
"I want :  spaces around all these marks  ;   :   !   ?  .  but i didn ’ t want it there in didn ’ t"

I want this:
"I want :  spaces around all these marks ;  :  !  ?  .  but i didn’t want it there in didn’t"

```
for(file in filelist){
  tx=readLines(file)
  tx2=gsub("(\\.+|[[:punct:]])", " \\1 ", tx)
  writeLines(tx2, con=file)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I get spaces all over with this?

Comment: Your pattern means that you want to replace `a...b` with `a ... b`. Do you want ``a . . . b``?

Comment: no a ... b (no spaces between dots) is great - but how would I do for a . . . b ? Thanks immensely for your help!

Comment: Please check the answer below and if there is something you need to change, please drop a comment there. 
See [my regex solution](https://regex101.com/r/AvZOZb/1) in action with `a . . . b`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```r
tx <- "I want: spaces around all these marks;:!?.but i didn’t want it there in didn't"
gsub("\\s*(\\.+|[[:punct:]])(?<!\\b['’]\\b)\\s*", " \\1 ", tx, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "I want : spaces around all these marks ;  :  !  ?  . but i didn’t want it there in didn't"
```

The `perl=TRUE` only means that the regex is handled with the PCRE library (note that PCRE regex engine is not the same as Perl regex engine).
See [the R demo online](https://ideone.com/t6xiz9) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eAHLLj/1).

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\.+|[[:punct:]])` - Group 1 (`\1`): one or more dots, or a punctuation char
- `(?<!\b['’]\b)` - immediately on the left, there must be no `'` or `’` enclosed with word chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces

Answer (score 1):

We may match the `'` and `SKIP` it before matching all other punctuation works

```
gsub("’(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([[:punct:].])", " \\1 ", tx, perl = TRUE)
```

-output

```
[1] "I want : spaces around all these marks ;  :  !  ?  .  but i didn’t want it there in didn’t"
```

#### data

```
tx <- "I want:spaces around all these marks;:!?. but i didn’t want it there in didn’t"
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! Sorry, but what does the perl = TRUE do?

Comment: @PascaleFM Accordng to `?gsub` `perl = logical. Should Perl-compatible regexps be used?`